# Reformatting text to return text before delimiter

Tags: bash, shell

I have been cleansing the following string of file names () as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

QUEUES='FILENAME1.WORLD1.J00.2D.00;FILENAME2.WORLD1.J01.2D.00;FILENAME3.WORLD1.J00.2D.00;FILENAME4.WORLD1.J01.2D.00;FILENAME5.WORLD1.J00.2D.00'

for i in $(echo $MQ_QUEUES | sed "s/;/ /g")
do
  a=$(echo "$i" | tr [:upper:] '[:lower:]' | sed 's/\./_/g')
  print $a
done
```

This currently produces a lower case version of the queue above with the full stop delimiter replaced by an underscore. But I now only want to grab the first section of the title. How would I do this?

I.e. so instead of `$a` returning `filename1_world1_j00_2d_00`, it would simply return `filename1`.

Comment: Your script had several syntax errors, which I've fixed since you didn't ask about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use awk? with:

`echo "$QUEUES" | tr ';' '\n' | awk -F'.' '{print tolower($1)}'`

you will get:

```
filename1
filename2
...
```